# An uncountable famliy in $2^\omega$ linearly ordered by inclusion without passing to $2^{\Bbb Q}$.

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

I was solving the problem of finding an uncountable, linearly ordered subset of $2^\omega$ ordered by inclusion. I was having a lot of trouble before I realized that I can substitute anything countably infinite for $\omega$. $\Bbb R$ defined by Dedekind cuts is a subset of $2^{\Bbb Q}$ linearly ordered by inclusion. Bijections agree with inclusion, so I'm done.

But I don't like this solution one bit. It's just a silly trick in my opinion, and I hoped for some illumination on the structure of $2^\omega$ when I was thinking about it. Before I realized this could be done by passing to $2^{\Bbb Q}$, I tried to think about it with Cantor's diagonal argument in mind. I was trying to construct (or define, perhaps using Zorn's lemma) a set of binary sequences that would satisfy the problem's requirements. I failed, but I would like to know if it can be done.

More generally, I would like to know if there is a solution to this problem that doesn't have a bijection jumbling everything up in it. Something where you can easily see the example in $2^\omega$

Comment: what's wrong with the lexicographic ordering ?

Comment: @mercio Could you elaborate on this? I don't understand what lexicographic ordering you have in mind.

Answer (score 4):

Probably you will consider this another silly trick. Since we can substitute any countably infinite set for $\omega$, let's use $S=\{x+iy:x,y=1,2,3,\dots\}$, the Gaussian integers in the first quadrant. For each angle $\theta\in(0,\frac{\pi}2)$ let $S_{\theta}=\{z\in S:0<\arg z<\theta\}$.

Here's another silly trick, using $\omega$ itself: for real $t>0$ let $A_t=\{2^x(2y+1):x,y\in\omega,\;y<tx\}$.

By the way, I don't consider the bijection between $\mathbb Q$ and $\omega$ a silly trick.

Comment: I like the last one using $2^x(2y-1)$ where $\omega$ is the positive integers. +1. (Note I think it should be $2y-1$ in order for $1$ to be included as the first odd natural number.)

Comment: I noticed later my version was off, and needed $x-1$ in the 2 exponent to get the odd positive integers. As you say in your other comment, dropping elements from the consideration doesn't change the validity of the example.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the best way I can think of to "fake" the Dedekind construction in $2^\omega$ directly without jumbling stuff up too much.

Split $\Bbb N$ into chunks $A_n=[2^n,2^{n+1})\cap\Bbb N$ for $n\in\Bbb N$. So the first chunk has 1 element, the second has the next two elements, the third has four, and so on. I propose to encode a real $x\in[0,1]$ by using each chunk as an approximation of the interval, of increasing refinement. Specifically,

$$f(x)=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}[2^n,2^n(1+x))\cap\Bbb N.$$

Clearly this is totally ordered w.r.t. inclusion, and it is also obviously injective and hence uncountable, because for any two different reals there is a refinement level (some $A_n$) such that the two reals are visibly separated.

[image: Faking a Dedekind cut]

In the figure above, the light-colored boxes are the numbers that are in the set. In this case, this is the initial segment of the encoding of $x=1/3$.

Comment: +1 This is a nice alternative way to encode $[0,1]$ as sets of naturals! The series method $A \leftrightarrow x = \sum\limits_{n>0} \chi_A(n) 2^{-n}$ gets boring after a while.

Comment: As a side note, I'll point out that this is another "faking" treatment with a hidden bijection, except I am using a bijection onto dyadic rationals, which are also dense in $\Bbb R$ and hence suitable for Dedekind cuts. (It's also not actually a bijection, but for these purposes a surjection is sufficient.)